# Berlin: Pay per use travel card for public transport

Tags: public-transport, berlin

I will be traveling to Berlin in June. I would like to know if there is a travel card I can buy and use across all the public transport options (bus,tram etc) for a week. Ideally, it could be a pay per use card for which I could get the balance refunded when I return the card.

Edit(replying to the comment): I prefer travel cards over single ride tickets for saving time. I want to avoid queues. I also want to avoid cases when I am not allowed to ride since I don't have the exact change(happened to me in Singapore). I later came to know that Singapore has this exact type of travel card which I am asking for :-)

Comment: "a pay per use card for which I could get the balance refunded when I return the card" - could you slightly extend your question to indicate whether (or why not) single-ride tickets (which are probably the most basic form of fare in any transportation system) are acceptable?

Comment: @O.R.Mapper edited the question.

Answer (score 7):

There is no option to get a refund on unused travel. There is a mobile payment system, but it requires you to provide your bank account and authorize direct debit.
Weekly tickets are not all that expensive and are valid across all means of public transport (bus, tram, U-Bahn, S-Bahn)
A weekly tickets for zones A and B costs around 30 Eur.
https://shop.bvg.de/index.php/group/63
https://shop.bvg.de/index.php/group/73

Comment: Also note that ticket machines only work with EC cards (German system), so don't expect Visa/MasterCard to work. They do take bills up to 20 Eur, but can also refuse to take them if the bill is wrinkled etc. If you see a BVG ticket office, do your shopping there, otherwise have various notes and coins just in case.

Comment: The weekly ticket is horrendously expensive compared to the monthly one. Some ticket machines do take 50 Euro bills as well, and the S-Bahn ones also do Visa/Master. All of them also do Geldkarte. Ticket machines are located on the S-Bahn and U-Bahn platforms or in the stations. There are no machines in tram stations. The machines are inside of trams and they are coins-only, and they do not do weekly or monthly tickets. In the bus you buy the ticket with the driver, cash-only, but they take bills up to the limit of change they have. Not sure if they do weekly tickets there.